# Saving a figure after invoking pyplot.show() results in an empty file

Tags: python, matplotlib

The following example code generates a simple plot, then saves it to 'fig1.pdf', then displays it, then saves it again to 'fig2.pdf'. The first image looks as expected, but the second one is blank (contains a white square). What's actually going on here? The line `plt.show()` apparently messes something up, but I can't figure out what/how!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
y = x**2
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.savefig('fig1.pdf')
plt.show()
plt.savefig('fig2.pdf')
```

Answer (score 131, accepted):

If you want to save the figure after displaying it, you'll need to hold on to the figure instance. The reason that `plt.savefig` doesn't work after calling `show` is that the current figure has been reset.

`pyplot` keeps track of which figures, axes, etc are "current" (i.e. have not yet been displayed with `show`) behind-the-scenes.  `gcf` and `gca` **g**et the **c**urrent **f**igure and current **a**xes instances, respectively.  `plt.savefig` (and essentially any other `pyplot` method) just does `plt.gcf().savefig(...)`.  In other words, get the current figure instance and call its `savefig` method.  Similarly `plt.plot` basically does `plt.gca().plot(...)`.

After `show` is called, the list of "current" figures and axes is empty.

In general, you're better off directly using the figure and axes instances to plot/save/show/etc, rather than using `plt.plot`, etc, to implicitly get the current figure/axes and plot on it. There's nothing wrong with using `pyplot` for everything (especially interactively), but it makes it easier to shoot yourself in the foot.

Use `pyplot` for `plt.show()` and to generate a figure and an axes object(s), but then use the figure or axes methods directly. (e.g. `ax.plot(x, y)` instead of `plt.plot(x, y)`, etc) The main advantage of this is that it's explicit.  You know what objects you're plotting on, and don't have to reason about what the pyplot state-machine does (though it's not that hard to understand the state-machine interface, either).

As an example of the "recommended" way of doing things, do something like:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
y = x**2

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
fig.savefig('fig1.pdf')
plt.show()
fig.savefig('fig2.pdf')
```

If you'd rather use the `pyplot` interface for everything, then just grab the figure instance before you call `show`. For example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
y = x**2

plt.plot(x, y)
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.savefig('fig1.pdf')
plt.show()
fig.savefig('fig2.pdf')
```

Comment: +1, Joe. This, IMO, demonstrates why the usage of the pyplot interface should be kept to a minimum.

Comment: Made g,c,f and g,c,a Bold in case someone misses. It makes very easy to remember the api for long run

Answer (score 6):

[pyplot.show](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.show) blocks and destroys the plot upon closing. You can use

```
plt.show(block=False)
```

after which the save to fig2.pdf will work or you can plot it again before saving

```
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.savefig('fig2.pdf')
```

Comment: That's not what `block` controls, for what it's worth. `block` controls whether or the gui toolkit's mainloop will block further execution or run in a separate thread.

Answer (score 2):

I had to run `plt.cla()` and `plt.clf()` before plotting the second one.  Clear current axes and clear current plot, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to see the figure before saving, you can call

```
plt.ion()
```

before plotting, which [starts interactive mode](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ion.html), and [shows all figures as they are drawn](https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-interactive-mode). This mostly removes the need to call `plt.show()`. You no longer need to close the figures to continue.

To disable interactive mode again, call `plt.ioff()`.