# Matplotlib multiple lines on graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've been having an issue with saving matplotlib graphs as images. 
The images are saving differently from what shows up when I call the .show() method on the graph. 
An example is here: 
http://s1.postimg.org/lbyei5cfz/blue5.png

I'm not sure what else to do. I've spent the past hours trying to figure out what's causing it, but I can't figure it out.

Here is my code in it's entirety.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
turn = 1 #for the x values
class Graph():
    def __init__(self, name, color):
        self.currentValue = 5 #for the y values
        self.x = [turn]
        self.y = [self.currentValue]
        self.name = name
        self.color = color 

    def update(self):
        if random.randint(0,1): #just to show if the graph's value goes up or down
            self.currentValue += random.randint(0,10)
            self.y.append(self.currentValue)
        else:
            self.currentValue -= random.randint(0,10)
            self.y.append(self.currentValue)
        self.x.append(turn)

    def plot(self):
        lines = plt.plot(self.x,self.y)
        plt.setp(lines, 'color',self.color)
        plt.savefig(self.name + str(turn))
        #plt.show() will have a different result from plt.savefig(args)

graphs = [Graph("red",'r'),Graph("blue",'b'),Graph("green",'g')]
for i in range(5):
    for i in graphs:
        i.update() #changes the x and y value
        i.plot() #saves the picture of the graph
    turn += 1
```

Sorry if this is a stupid mistake I'm making, I just find it peculiar how plt.show() and plt.savefig are different.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated correctly by David, `plt.show()` resets current figure. `plt.savefig()`, however, does not, so you need to reset it explicitly. [`plt.clf()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.clf) or [`plt.figure()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.figure) are two functions that can do it dor you. Just insert the call right after `plt.savefig`:

```
    plt.savefig(self.name + str(turn))
    plt.clf()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save the figure after displaying it, you'll need to hold on to the figure instance. The reason that `plt.savefig` doesn't work after calling `show` is that the current figure has been reset.

`pyplot` keeps track of which figures, axes, etc are "current" (i.e. have not yet been displayed with `show`) behind-the-scenes.  `gcf` and `gca` get the current figure and current axes instances, respectively.  `plt.savefig` (and essentially any other `pyplot` method) just does `plt.gcf().savefig(...)`.  In other words, get the current figure instance and call its `savefig` method.  Similarly `plt.plot` basically does `plt.gca().plot(...)`.

After `show` is called, the list of "current" figures and axes is empty.

In general, you're better off directly using the figure and axes instances to plot/save/show/etc, rather than using `plt.plot`, etc, to implicitly get the current figure/axes and plot on it. There's nothing wrong with using `pyplot` for everything (especially interactively), but it makes it easier to shoot yourself in the foot.

Use `pyplot` for `plt.show()` and to generate a figure and an axes object(s), but then use the figure or axes methods directly. (e.g. `ax.plot(x, y)` instead of `plt.plot(x, y)`, etc) The main advantage of this is that it's explicit.  You know what objects you're plotting on, and don't have to reason about what the pyplot state-machine does (though it's not that hard to understand the state-machine interface, either).

As an example of the "recommended" way of doing things, do something like:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
y = x**2

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
fig.savefig('fig1.pdf')
plt.show()
fig.savefig('fig2.pdf')
```

If you'd rather use the `pyplot` interface for everything, then just grab the figure instance before you call `show`. For example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
y = x**2

plt.plot(x, y)
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.savefig('fig1.pdf')
plt.show()
fig.savefig('fig2.pdf')
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21884187/4240314)

Comment: After reviewing your Questions again, my Answer might be completely irrelevant... my brain isn't functioning tonight; If so, down vote accordingly and i'll delete my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It should be noted, however, that doing the method you showed me, DID work, however, it used a massive amount of RAM. (Nearly 1Gb for what I was doing).
Simply putting plt.clf() to clear the graph was much more efficient.