# Matplotlib in pyramid-pylons app with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, matplotlib, sqlalchemy, pyramid

Am in a stage in my application where am trying to comeup with a statistics interface(graphs,charts) based on the data in the sqlalchemy database am using. However I came across matplotlib and i am trying to get along along with it but still failing to implement it. Am using Mako templates.
Am requesting on how to go about this.Thanks
heres sam view's code.

```py
@view_config(route_name="d", renderer="./templates/d.mako")
def d(request):
    try:
       rows = DBSession.query(Song.duration, Song.price).all()
       duration,price = zip(*rows)
       plt.plot(duration,price)
       ##show()
    except DBAPIError:
    return Response(conn_err_msg, content_type='text/plain', status_int=500)
return { 'project': 'beatstore'}
```

Comment: If you post some code and an explanation of what you want it to do, and what is going wrong we can start to help you.

Comment: I have edited it, my issue is returning plotted results on mako template

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21875356/saving-a-figure-after-invoking-pyplot-show-results-in-an-empty-file) for how to save a map after generating it, then just put it inside static and render as an image with your template.