# Bars not showing when saving chart to png

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, png

me very new programmer, I having problem with saving bar chart to png, bars aren't showing up.

My Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 3
ind = np.arange(N)
width = 0.35

Start_means = (100, 50, 50)
Start_std = (2, 3, 4)

End_means = (80, 30, 30)
End_std = (3, 5, 2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(ind, Start_means, width, color='xkcd:red', yerr=Start_std)
rects2 = ax.bar(ind+width, End_means, width, color='xkcd:black', yerr=End_std)

ax.legend((rects1[0], rects2[0]), ('Start', 'End'))
ax.set_ylabel('Available')
ax.set_title('Travel availability, by tour')
ax.set_xticks(ind + width/2)
countries = ['Italy', 'China', 'France']
ids = ['ID:12345', 'ID:13579', 'ID:24680']

xlabels = []
for i, j in zip(countries, ids):
    xlabels.append(i + '\n' + j)

ax.set_xticklabels(xlabels)

def autolabel(rects):
    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2., 1.05*height,
                '%d' % int(height),
                ha='center', va='bottom')
autolabel(rects1)
autolabel(rects2)

plt.show()
plt.savefig('barchart.png')
```

What it should look like: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/278ll.jpg)
I'd like to save it as a png file, but it just comes up blank without the bars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to swap the order in which the `plt.show()` appears and the `plt.savefig('barchart.png')`

```
plt.savefig('barchart.png')
plt.show()
```

> The reason that plt.savefig doesn't work after calling show is that
>   the current figure has been reset.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21884187/1577947