# Empty figures in python and cannot save the figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here is the code of plotting the figures. But why  are there always two empty figures before the third expected figure, it seems I created two blank fig.

And I cannot save the figure in my local computer `fig.savefig('Sens.png')`. There is an error `The C++ part of the object has been deleted, attribute access no longer allowed`(actually successfully saved only for one time).

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
m = 1
for s in dataList:
   plt.subplot(2,2,m)
   f = interp1d(FXSpotList, s, 'cubic')    
   xnew = np.linspace(FXSpotList[0], FXSpotList[-1], 40, True)
   plt.plot(xnew, f(xnew), '-')
   plt.xlabel('Spot')
   plt.ylabel(titleList[m-1])
   plt.axvline(x=tradeTest.Pair().Spot(), linestyle='--')  
   plt.axhline(y=0, linestyle='--')
   m = m + 1

plt.figtext(0.5, 0.01, 'Type='+str(tradeTest.Types()[0]), ha='center')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
plt.close()
fig.savefig('Sens.png')
```

Comment: For the issue with saving, you should take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21875356/saving-a-figure-after-invoking-pyplot-show-results-in-an-empty-file

Comment: For the 2 empty figures, the code looks ok, it will probably be a problem with your data. Try to generate an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and in the process you'll likely find the issue

Comment: @user6703592 Can you please rollback the misleading changes introduced to your code and format it according to your intention?

Answer (score 2):

Although you did not provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it is obvious that there are things wrong with your loop construction. You show, close, then save the plot in every loop, which is probably not, what you are intending to do. A minimal example of your loop would be

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

#sample list to iterate over
dataList = ["fig1", "fig2", "fig3"]

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
#loop over the list, retrieve data entries and index
for i, s in enumerate(dataList):
    #define position of the plot in a 2 x 2 grid
    plt.subplot(2, 2, i + 1)
    #random plot, insert your calculations here
    plt.plot(range(3), np.random.randint(0, 10, 3))
    #utilize list data
    plt.title(s)

#save figure
plt.savefig('test.png') 
#show figure
plt.show()
```

Comment: Initially the saving was outside the loop. When the post was edited, the indentation was modified.

Comment: @xg.plt.py Meh. Who approves edits that create pseudoproblems? ... I better check it was not me.

Comment: @Mr.T thanks, the later part of my code should be outside the loop, it's a  typo. And it seems that I should save the fig before the `plt.show()`, but I have closed the fig after showing, why can not I save the fig?

Comment: @user6703592 After correcting the indentation, your `plt.close` is redundant, because `plt.show` is blocking and you will execute `plt.close` anyhow, when you close the shown figure. This destroys the figure instance. To my surprise, you can still access the data from `fig`, which includes saving `fig`. But you can't modify it, because matplotlib considers this application destroyed. This doesn't solve your problem at all but as it is stated now, I can't replicate your error message.