# Cant plot an Python matplotlib figure in pdf

Tags: python, matplotlib

I know that my question sounds desperate and also it is not a short reproducible example. However I am writing my thesis and I tried a test print. I couldnt print the document, written in TeX and viewed in pdf, because of one plot that is based on python (all other ones are created in R). I would be so gratefull to someone how could have a quick look at it. I'm really desperate right now because I don't want to take this graphic out of my work. I am not really familiar with python as I am using R, but just wanted to generate this plot for my thesis.

[the Code](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/xavierbourretsicotte/Data-Portfolio/blob/master/Crossvalidated%20-%20Ridge%20Lasso%20regression%20path.ipynb).

I am referring to the figure in the section "Lasso coordinate descent
Vary parameter l (lamda) for different results" (field [20]).

I am trying to save it as follows:

```
    %matplotlib inline
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (16,8))

#Surface plot
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(T1, T2, Z, rstride = 5, cstride = 5, cmap = 'jet', alpha=0.5)
ax.plot(theta_0,theta_1,J_history_lasso, marker = '*', color = 'r', alpha = .4, label = 'Gradient descent')

ax.set_xlabel('theta 1')
ax.set_ylabel('theta 2')
ax.set_zlabel('error')
ax.set_title('RSS gradient descent: Root at {}'.format(theta_result_lasso.ravel()))
ax.view_init(25, -40)


#Contour plot
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2)
ax.contour(T1, T2, Z, 100, cmap = 'jet')
ax.quiver(theta_0[:-1], theta_1[:-1], anglesx, anglesy, scale_units = 'xy', angles = 'xy', scale = 1, color = 'r', alpha = .9)



 ax.set_xlabel(r'$\beta_1$', fontsize=20, labelpad = 10)
 ax.set_ylabel(r'$\beta_2$', fontsize=20, labelpad = 10)
 ax.set_zlabel(r'$\mathcal{L}(\beta)$', fontsize=20, labelpad = 10)
 ax.tick_params(labelsize=16)
 ax.set_title(r'Globales Minimum $\hat \beta$ = [{:0.0f}, {:0.2f}]'.format(roundi[0],roundi[1]), fontsize=20, pad=40)

 plt.show()

 fig.savefig("l18.pdf", bbox_inches='tight')
```

but I cant print out the regarding pdf. I also tried different types of printers. So it should be problem with the regarding figure.

Comment: It is an exception that it contradicts the usual format of this Forum.

Comment: just comment the line `plt.show()`

Comment: I'll try give me a second

Comment: Have you tried saving the figure as a png, and then linking it to the tex document?

Comment: I'll try both Solutions, thanks to you guys

Comment: `plt.show()` shows your figure. My guess is that you are closing it pressing on the `x` button and so stopping the execution. If you comment it `#plt.show()` you will reach the `savefig` command. See e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21875356/saving-a-figure-after-invoking-pyplot-show-results-in-an-empty-file

Comment: I also saved it as pdf. The pdf file is produced, but I cant print the regarding pdf file. Are there maybe some other formats to save it  ?

Comment: It works as png but the resolution isnt quite well. Maybe the dpi of the pdf figure is too high or something

Comment: Try saving it as `.eps` and use `eps2pdf` convertor to convert to pdf. Or just use eps files in your LaTeX thesis. eps are vector plots and have really good resolutions

Comment: I'll try, you think that this could work ?

Comment: Of course. I have already tried this. In your latex compiler, you will have to choose the option of ps--> pdf during compilation. Just google for more on your TeX editor...whichever you are using

Comment: The eps version works ! I can print the thesis at my home printer. So it will also be printed by a professional one. You saved my night :D Do you want to write an answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try saving it as `.eps` and use `eps2pdf` convertor to convert to `pdf`. Or just use `.eps` files in your `LaTeX` thesis. `eps` are vector plots and have really good resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

`plt.show()` shows the picture and *clears the canvas*. Your PDF file is empty. That's why you cannot print it. Either remove `plt.show()` or move it after the `savefig`.